# Can I send commits to Android with new langue locale and keyboard layouts?

Tags: android-source

Can I send a commit once I have figured out how to add a language (Kurdish)  which is still not in Android source code upto API 28?

Bonus: where would you start from? Link to few files/folders that need changing in AOSP such as here:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror

Feel free to mark it as a duplicate question but I could not find one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Submitting Patches**

Yes, you can create patches and send them to Androids review server for approval. Android even has a tutorial on how to do that: https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/submit-patches.
Note that the official git server for Android is https://android.googlesource.com

**Adding Locales**

Ideally, you wouldn't have to contribute to the official AOSP repositories just to add a custom locale. But it [looks like](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/core/build-system.html#197) custom vendor locales are not (yet) supported. You will likely (I have zero experience with adding locales) have to update at least [external/icu/icu4c/source/data/lang](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/refs/heads/master/icu4c/source/data/lang) and [build/make/target/product/languages_full.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/master/target/product/languages_full.mk).

Did you notice that there might already be a [kurdish locale in icu4c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/refs/heads/master/icu4c/source/data/lang/ku.txt)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you possibly give me any more on Locale and keyboard layouts? Just to be sure, having invested weeks in finding out how to do this then get rejected because of some internal/external policy. Languages and locales are "sensitive" stuff, I would think.

Comment: Now I have a little more time Paul, that is a great answer. I can see as you say there is KU and [CKB](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/refs/heads/master/icu4c/source/data/lang/ckb.txt). This is strange, why does my code [here](https://github.com/layik/kurdi/issues/6#issuecomment-513539762) shows nothing in API 28 or I can not see it in an S10 Android 9 device?

Comment: icu4c is an external package to Android. The icu4c maintainers added the kurdish locale, but the Android maintainers did not. Maybe because not all other packages in the AOSP support it.